# Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand why this error is appearing in my table, I couldn't find similarities in other questions around here.

```
function Table({ data }) {
  return (
    <table className="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {data["columns"].filter((header) => {
            if (!header.includes("noheader")) {
              return <th key={header}>{header}</th>;
            } else {
              return false;
            }
          })}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Raised error
Line 15:53:  Array.prototype.filter() expects a value to be returned at the end of arrow function  array-callback-return

Comment: Filter method only returns those elements for which its callback returns true. Solution: 1. Filter the `data["columns"]` array with those headers that don't include `'noheader'`. 2. Use the `map()` method to return `<th>` element: `data['columns'].filter(...).map(header => <th>...</th>)`

Comment: You need to use `map` function instead of `filter` and return null in the else part

Comment: Don't return a component in the filter. Filter with a boolean and then map the results. `filter(x => x.includes('noheader')).map ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use `filter` to get an array containing only the headers you want (minus `noheader`). Then use `map` to iterate through all the headers in that array and render them.

```
data["columns"].filter(header => (!(header.includes("noheader")))).map(header =>
        return <th key = { header} > { header } < /th>;)
```

Answer (score 4):

`filter` expects a boolean to be returned for each item in the array you are filtering. If true is returned the item is added in the resulting array.

If you want to alter the array instead of filtering it use another method, like `map`

Answer (score 1):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) wants a return of true or false to determine whether the new array will contain the element it is checking.  If you want to mutate the array in some way, you may want to consider [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), as it can both filter and mutate the returned array (or really do many other things as well).

Answer (score 1):

Filter this array first. Then you can use .map()

```
 function Table({ data }) {
  return (
    <table className="main-table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          {data["columns"].filter((e => !e.includes("noheader")).map(header => <th key={header}>{header}</th>))}
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and solved it by returning null. (return null will never be reached anyways in my case):

```
{showLocked && LockedAchievements && LockedAchievements.filter((val) => {
    if (searchTerm === "") {
        return val;
    } else if (val.props.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())) {
        return val
    } else {
        return null;
    }
})}
```

Comment: So you have two conditions which both return the same value, and then you had to add an else which will never be reached? Why are you doing this at all then? Why not just `.filter(val => val)` or more cleanly `.filter(Boolean)`?